# Globus GridFtp truncates end lines in text files

Tags: ftp, text, binary

I am using this configurations for the server side:

- Globus gridFTP server 10.6 (1467236171-85)
- Fedora 22, 64-bit GNOME Version 3.16.2

As for the client side I am using different clients:

- libcurl based client
- FileZilla.

I upload files from a Windows machine to Globus gridFTP server on a Linux machine. I upload files on **binary mode**, but the text files are automatically changed (line endings are truncated) on the server side. Data is send correctly over the network (checked with Wireshark).

For example, I have an `a.txt` file on Windows containing `61 0d 0a 62` (a end line b). If I upload data to a file with extension `txt` the end line is truncated and the size of the file will be different than the original. If I upload data to a file with extension `so` (for example) date is fine and the size is the same as on the Windows machine.

What can I do to preserve transferred data for the text files also?